# Searchkick - Elasticsearch - Names with underscore instead of white space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

we have tags example:

```
hello_my_name_is

Tag.search "hello"
=> []
```

But when trying to search for `hello` with searchkick/elasticsearch we dont get anything in the results. We explicitly need to search for `hello_my_name_is` in order to get it.

```
Tag.search "hello_my_name_is"
=> [{name: "hello_my_name_is"...}]
```

Is there some way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch cares about what type of search you're performing. In this case, the default is a match of the entire word. One way to solve your problem would be to use the [partial matches](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#partial-matches) functionality of the searchkick gem.

```
Tag.search "hello", fields: [:name], match: :word_start
```

Don't forget to reindex after you make your changes.

Comment: I ended up using ```:word_middle```